# What numeric values are GeneXus' .open method return

Tags: genexus

I try to import excel file on Genexus.
I use .open to make sure that selected file is excel file like this.

---

```
&ret = &w_Excel.Open(&w_FilePath)               
&w_Excel.Close()

If &ret = 0
//import excel deta
Else
//show message 'this is not excel file'
EndIf
```

---

On the develop environment, this code works well.
But another environment, this one does not.

I'm guessing that .open method returns 0 
whether the selected file is excel file or is not.

I understood that .open returns 0 when the excel file was selected.
And it returns 10 when other file types.
Is it correct?

I'm not sure because this site just says  return a Numeric type.
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6992,Open+Method,

Does the values that .open returns changes by running enviroment?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6939,Error+Codes+and+Messages+for+ExcelDocument) 0 (zero) means everything went Ok, but there are some more codes you should check for.

**EDIT**: Try to get the [ErrorDescription](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6931,ErrDescription%20Property) for detailed info about the error.

`&w_Excel.ErrorDescription`

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file exists before you try to open the file
using, for example, a variable &File of type File: If &file.exists() ...

The open() method will create the file if the file doesn't exist.

So first check if the file exists, then open it.